# jquery submit onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick

how do i get an input type="submit" onclick event to fire the commitfunds.valdiate? i can't use a class or id. it must be an onclick event.

here's the code:

```
<?
foreach ($db->row AS $val){
$("#commitfunds<?=$val['id']?>").validate({
submitHandler: function(form){
    $.post('/pages/aditorials/add_to_cart.php',
$("#commitfunds<?=$val['id']?>").serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#wb_fundsresults<?=$val['id']?>').html(data);
    });
}
});


<form>
<input type="text" name="commit_funds">
<input type="submit" onclick="$(#commitfunds).validate()<?=$val['id']?>;return false;">
</form>
<div id="#wb_fundsresults<?=$val['id']?>"></div>

?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
// do your stuff
});
```

**EDIT: 11/11/14**

You can use .[submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
// do your stuff
});
```

Comment: or check for the form being submitted `$('form').submit(function() { /* do stuff */ });`

Comment: thanks for the answers. are these for the jquery function or the onlick event? i need it for the onlick event. user clicks the submit button fires the onclick event which then executes the jquery function.